# Laravel 9 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello i'm trying to use eloquent in my code:

```
        $nr_riga = 0;
        
        foreach($data_detail as $key => $row_detail) {
            
            $nr_riga = $key + 1;

            $new_orders_details->nr_riga = $nr_riga;
            $new_orders_details->codice_articolo = $row_detail['codice_articolo'];
            $new_orders_details->quantita = $row_detail['quantita'];
            $new_orders_details->prezzo = $row_detail['prezzo'];
            $new_orders_details->order_id = $new_orders_grid->id;
            $new_orders_details->save();
            
            // DB::table('orders_detail')->insert([

            //     'order_id' => $new_orders_details->order_id,

            //     'nr_riga' => $nr_riga,

            //     'codice_articolo' => $new_orders_details->codice_articolo,
                
            //     'quantita' => $new_orders_details->quantita,
                
            //     'prezzo' => $new_orders_details->prezzo,
                
                
            //     ]);
            
        }
```

This loop works both ways but not equally.. when i use $new_orders_details->save(); it inserts to the db a single row,seems to not looping.

DB::table('orders_detail')->insert does the job as i want.

How to convert it to eloquent for have same result?

This is the db screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create new model instance in loop.

$new_orders_details = new OrderSDetail();

Comment: Yes it was the missing part! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, can you try this solution?

```
$ordersDetail = new OrderSDetail();

$ordersDetail->insert([ //your data here]);
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Basically I wrote the same thing as the accepted answer but okay :D @shaddark

Comment: Sorry but the other answer was more specific as i needed, i marked as useful anyway :)
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can prepare date in loop and make one batch insert using Model::insert($your_data)

Saving in loop it is not best way to save data to db
Like:

```
$data = [];

foreach($data_detail as $key => $row_detail) {
    
    $nr_riga = $key + 1;

    $data[]['nr_riga'] = $nr_riga;
    $data[]['codice_articolo'] = $row_detail['codice_articolo'];
    $data[]['quantita'] = $row_detail['quantita'];
    $data[]['prezzo'] = $row_detail['prezzo'];
    $data[]['order_id'] = $new_orders_grid->id;
}

NewOrderDetails::insert($data);
```

It is save all you data with using model